# Return statement in Switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to be able to return each of the review in the following switch statement, At the moment, only the first review is being returned. What could be the problem?

```
var getReview = function (food) {        
    switch (food) {    
        case "Pancakes":
            console.log("The Kids love it");
            break;           
        case "Pasta":
            console.log("Popular Italian food");
            break;                
        case "Naan":
            console.log("Asian bread");
            break;            
        default:
            console.log("Don't like food?");
            break;
    }

    return food;
};
```

Comment: How are you calling `getReview()`?

Comment: getReview is the function name

Comment: Currently, the function is just returning the value that's passed into it, so no review is going to be returned. What Sayem meant by his question is that he wants you to show us the code where you are _calling_ the function.

Comment: When you say that you want to return the review, do you mean return it from the function or display it in the console? Right now the function does't return any review at all, just the value that you sent in.

Comment: @matic1088: Yes, that I can see. But how are you actually _invoking_ it? Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: I want to diplay it in the console @Guffa

Comment: @matic1088 well you are already displaying it in the *console*. And in case; you don't need to `return` anything at all

Comment: @matic1088: The code does that. Here is an example that shows the review for pasta: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/YyH8R/

Comment: You still haven't answered Sayem's question. You should also tell us how the current behavior differs from your desired behavior.

Comment: Its an assignment I have been given.. @SayemAhmed,  I have been told to project all the reviews in the console and i decided to write this code. I wanted to know if its wright or wrong

Comment: That doesn't answer Sayem's question, or my question, and the fact that it's an assignment is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var getReview = function (food) {
     var review;
     switch (food) {

         case "Pancakes":
             review = "The Kids love it";
             break;

         case "Pasta":
             review = "Popular Italian food";
             break;


         case "Naan":
             review = "Asian bread";
             break;

         default:
             review = "Don't like food?";
             break;
     }
     console.log(review);
     return review;
 };

var review = getReview('Pancakes'); //Return value = The Kids love it, Console = The Kids love it
```

Comment: You could put the `console.log` after the `switch` statement. No need to have it in every `case` block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to, however, it would be useful to define the function like this:

```
var getReview = function (food) {
  switch (food){
  case "Pancakes":
    return "The Kids love it";
  case "Pasta":
    return "Popular Italian food";
  case "Naan":
    return "Asian bread";
  default:
    return "Don't like food?";
  }
};
```

After you have function like this, you can get the result like the followings:

```
getReview('Pancakes');
=> 'The Kids love it'

getReview('Paster');
=> 'Popular Italian food'
...
```